# how to display all the distinct 7-digit number among 2 to 9?

Tags: c, distinct-values

what i mean is all the numbers _ _ _ _ _ _ _ are distinct and only values 2 to 9 can be entered. I've tried using array and loops but i just couldn't figure out the solution to display all the numbers. 
examples 7-digit number among 2 to 9 are:
234567
234568
234569

324567
324568
324569

notice the none of the numbers in those values are repeated.
I really have no idea what's going on.
please help me!

Comment: The keyword you are looking for is "permutations".

Comment: I love that all your examples of 7-digit numbers have 6 digits...

Comment: I avoid answering homework question without attempted code. Just don't want to encourage lazy students. And I kind of sense that this one is. Whether this is homework or not, post the code you have tried and we can go from there. I think this will be more useful to you.

Comment: I consider it poor form to add the homework tag when there's *no* indication it is. There is plenty of examples in the past where it was simple self-education.

Comment: with a system like this that one can vote and down vote where points are added or subtracted based on answer one gives, it doesn't matter whether you think its homework or not. Those that post just want to get points, that's all. Me included. This is very similar to if OP pays me money to do his homework.

Comment: pax, the 'C' tag should stay, the OP has indicated in the comments below that it's a C question

Comment: i was doing exercise in my textbook but this problem came out and i was stuck.. opss.. sorry.. it's 7-digit... hehe..

Comment: Yeah, I saw that after the comment and put it back in. Apologies. Still ,the homework tag shouldn't be put in unless the OP states so.

Comment: keitamike, is this homework, or self-education???

Comment: keitamike, usual practice once you've solved the problem is to upvote those answers that helped and accept the one that helped the most. Use the up-arrows next to the answer for the first, and the green tick for the second.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't specify a language, here's a Haskell answer.

```
import Control.Monad

selectPerms :: MonadPlus m => [a] -> Int -> m [a]
selectPerms _        0 = return []
selectPerms universe n = do
    (digit, remain) <- selectDigit universe
    xs <- selectPerms remain (n - 1)
    return (digit:xs)

selectDigit :: MonadPlus m => [a] -> m (a, [a])
selectDigit [] = mzero
selectDigit (x:xs) = capture `mplus` next
    where
        capture = return (x, xs)
        next = do
            (digit, remain) <- selectDigit xs
            return (digit, x:remain)

yourAnswer :: [[Int]]
yourAnswer = selectPerms [2..9] 7
```

Comment: Much better (but wordier) than the obvious `import Data.List; nub $ map (take 7) (permutations [1..9])` :)  It still reads nicely, though.

Comment: @keitamike You really should say these things somewhere, like in the tags :)

Comment: C'mon, how hard can it be to translate Haskell to C. OMG, my eyes are bleeding! :-)

Comment: Come now, it's really quite simple! I just select an arbitrary permutation, then use `[]`'s `MonadPlus` instance to expand that over all possible permutations. Easy! :)

Answer (score 1):

Since this sounds suspiciously like homework, the education here will be a gradual process. First, try brute force. Here's an algorithm (well, Python really) that will do it:

```
for n1 in range(2,10):
  for n2 in range(2,10):
    if n2 != n1:
      for n3 in range(2,10):
        if n3 != n2 and n3 != n1:
          for n4 in range(2,10):
            if n4 != n3 and n4 != n2 and n4 != n1:
              for n5 in range(2,10):
                if n5 != n4 and n5 != n3 and n5 != n2 and n5 != n1:
                  for n6 in range(2,10):
                    if n6 != n5 and n6 != n4 and n6 != n3 and n6 != n2 and n6 != n1:
                      for n7 in range(2,10):
                        if n7 != n6 and n7 != n5 and n7 != n4 and n7 != n3 and n7 != n2 and n7 != n1:
                          print "%d%d%d%d%d%d%d"%(n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6,n7)
```

It's basically seven nested loops, one for each digit position, with checks that there's no duplicates at any point. Note that this is not a solution that will scale well for *lots* of digit positions, but it performs quite well for seven of them. If you want many more, a less brute-force solution would be better.

Comment: thanks for your teaching. i think this works for me.. i'm trying now

Comment: Shouldn't be too hard to do the same thing in C. I don't want to post the C code in case it's homework since you should be doing *some* of the work :-)

Comment: thanks for your answer. it really do help me in my problems. thanks everybody!

Answer (score 1):

There are 7!=5040 ways to permute abcdefg.

There are <sub>9</sub>C<sub>7</sub>=36 ways to choose 7 numbers out of 123456789.

Given a permutation "bfgdeac" and a set of {1,3,4,5,6,8,9}, there is a natural way to use the permutation to provide an order for the set, i.e. [3,8,9,5,6,1,4].

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Borrowed from Python's [itertools docs](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations).

```
def permutations(iterable, r=None):
    # http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    r = n if r is None else r
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = range(n)
    cycles = range(n, n-r, -1)
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices[:r])
    while n:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            cycles[i] -= 1
            if cycles[i] == 0:
                indices[i:] = indices[i+1:] + indices[i:i+1]
                cycles[i] = n - i
            else:
                j = cycles[i]
                indices[i], indices[-j] = indices[-j], indices[i]
                yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices[:r])
                break
        else:
            return
for number in permutations('23456789',6): # you said 7, but your examples were 6
    print number
```

**Edit:** Or if you have Python anyways...

```
import itertools
for number in itertools.permutations('23456789',6): print number
```